# Need Help in Bash debugging

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop

Im trying to run this code . Basically I want the   https://admin:qwerty123@'"$dmp"':7777/set_param?'"$params
 command to run 3 times for every ip in array. But Im getting errors like

```
prog.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `while'
prog.sh: line 7: `while [ $n -lt 3 ]; do'
```

Please can someone correct the code

```
#!/bin/bash 

n="0"
dmps=(10.104.164.104 10.35.176.77 10.35.176.126) # *****  put your dmp ips here *******

for dmp in ${dmps[@]}; 
while [ $n -lt 3 ]; do


  do res=$(curl -k -s --url 'https://admin:qwerty123@'"$dmp"':7777/set_param?'"$params"); 
  echo "DMP: $dmp - $res"; 
n=$[n+1]
done

done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- add space before `[`
- add `; do` after `]`

  ```
  while [ n -lt 3 ]; do
  ```

[read more](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs)

Comment: hi kev, actually I edited the code in original post. That is what I wanted. BUt In that Im getting error like prog.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `while'
prog.sh: line 7: `while [ $n -lt 3 ]; do'

Comment: you have two `do`s after **while**. you should [read more](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) to fix syntax error.

Comment: You still lack a `do` in the `for`. The proper syntax is `for var in list ... ; **do** stuff; done`